# Grid is not in fullscreeen

Tags: html, css

My assignment is about creating a poster. My idea is creating a grid system. I made a grid but it is not fullscreen as I wanted. Anyone can help me with this. Here is my problem. I tried changing the width and height but it's not working.

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid_section {
    
}

.grid_section .grid_container {
    display: inline-grid;
    background-color: black;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto; 
    column-gap: 5px;
    row-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid_section .grid_container .grid_item {
    background-color: rgb(29, 216, 29);
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid_section">
        <div class="grid_container">
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
            <div class="grid_item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want a `display: inline-grid` and not a `display: grid`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information. how many columns and rows do you want in the grid? what is the size of each grid?

Anyway, I just added width and height using `vw` and `vh` and it works normally. so what exactly is the issue here?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid_section .grid_container {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto; 
    column-gap: 5px;
    row-gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid_section .grid_container .grid_item {
    background-color: rgb(29, 216, 29);
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grid_section">
      <div class="grid_container">
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
          <div class="grid_item"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```